# Complexifying a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, complex-geometry

I've encountered this operation a few times now and I don't really understand its meaning. Given a vector space $V $ we can "complexify" it by the operation $V\mapsto  V\otimes \mathbb {C} $.

First of all, a sanity check - this tensor product is over the reals, right? Secondly, how do I imagine this complexified version and why is the tensor product with the complex plane the right way to do it? I do not need an extensive explanation about tensor analysis, just intuition on this apparatus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this tensor product is over the deals, right?

This tensor product is over whatever field your vector space $V$ is over. So it's probably the reals, yes, but it might well also be the rationals or whatever.

> how do I imagine this complexified version

Intuitively: it's the same thing, just that you're now allowed complex coefficients.

> why is the tensor product with the complex plane the right way to do it?

It might help you to try to prove the following: if $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$, then $V\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with basis $\hat{v}_1, \dots, \hat{v}_n$, where $\hat{v}_i = v_i\otimes 1$.

(Once you get comfortable with the object $V\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$, you can safely abuse notation slightly and drop the hats.)

Comment: In the case of the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_2$, how do you get the complexification $V\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\mathbb{C}$ when $V$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ vector space? Is it possible to see $\mathbb{C}$ as a left $\mathbb{Z}_2$ module or $\mathbb{Z}_2$ vector space?

Comment: @ChoF: Nope. You can only write down the tensor product $-\otimes_A B$ when there is a (ring) homomorphism $A\to B$. (When $A$ and $B$ are fields, the only non-trivial homomorphisms are inclusion maps, like the map that views $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.) So this tensor product you've written down doesn't make sense.